# Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

My spring application have problem with save 'date" to "database". where is mistake?

[image]

error

> Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to
>   required type [java.sql.Date] for property bornDate; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date:
>   Unparseable date: "2016-11-02"

mysql

```
use lifecalc;
create table Man (
manId int not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(30) not null,
bornDate date,
lastDate date
);
insert into man value
(null, "Pawel Cichon", "1920-11-30", "2000-02-20");
```

entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Man")
public class Man {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="manId")
    private int manId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column
    private java.sql.Date bornDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column
    private java.sql.Date lastDate;
    //getter end setter
```

controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private ManService manService;

    @ModelAttribute("man")
    public Man modelToAddMan(){
        return new Man();
    }

    @InitBinder
     public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor( dateFormat, true));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addMan.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addManFinish(@Valid @ModelAttribute("man") Man man, BindingResult result) {

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "addMan";
        } else{
            manService.addMan(man);
            return "redirect:/index.html";
        }
    }
```

addMan.html

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="man">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">name</label>
        <form:input path="name" />
        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bornDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">bornDate</label>
        <form:input   path="bornDate"  />
        <form:errors path="bornDate" cssClass="error"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">lastDate</label>
        <form:input  path="lastDate"  />
        <form:errors path="lastDate" cssClass="error"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save" /> <a
            class="btn btn-danger" role="button"
            href="<spring:url value="/index.html" />">cancel </a>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Comment: what date format you are getting inputted from your addMan.html , is it yyyy/MM/dd or yyy-MM-dd?

Comment: "yyyy/mm/dd" is not valid it should be "yyyy/MM/dd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column
private java.sql.Date bornDate;
```

Use java.util.date:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column
private java.util.date bornDate;
```